# Unable to get security token for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do some basic performance testing on an app I look after.

I am using Jmeter and done the steps recorder and the same as following Jmeter tutorials on youtube, but I am getting stuck when I need put the variable into the X-CSRF-Token

The issue is I cant find X-CSRF-Token in the captured steps. Is it using some other form of authentication? Any suggestions for me as to other methods would be great.

If the post doesn't make much sense, I don't really have an in-depth knowledge of Jmeter or testing.

Comment: Any feedback on answers ? If ok you should accept one and upvote so that answer is safely usable by others.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To find where the token appeared:

- clear browser history
- record your scenario using jmeter recording template
- then in the view result tree located un HTTP(s) Test Script recorder, use the search field to find the first response in which it appears. You’ll need to add an extractor in the corresponding sampler
- you ‘ll then be able to inject it using ${varName}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server configuration this `X-CSRF-Token` can come in:

- In the response HTML body
- In the [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), inspect [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) for any hard-coded values
- As a [HTTP Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) (which is basically a header as well, however it will be much more convenient to get it from the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) rather than from response headers)

So make sure to inspect all the tabs of the first request in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as this `X-CSRF-Token` guy can hide anywhere.

You can try an alternative way of recording a JMeter test, it can export test in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of any dynamic parameters including but not limited to [CSRF tokens](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens) so theoretically it can make your life easier, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for more information and technical details.

If you need further help you will have to provide more details, like full dump of 2 requests along with responses. You can use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture it.

Comment: How is the best way to upload a dump?
I have digging around the headers and body, I have these lines in the Response headers:

Set-Cookie: pu=671121fb-c657-476c-b2d1-d873b27514b9; secure; expires=Thu, 19-Apr-2018 22:51:43 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=aaadcvbxOj7vyeeBk-djw; path=/; secure; HttpOnly

From what I can tell that pu= GUID seems to change when I do a new capture. I am not sure if that is what I should be collecting, or which piece of code puts it there.